# How to pass fuzzyMatch param to mapbox geocoding api

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-api-geocoding

I am using MapboxAPI for geocoding but I am experiencing it is tending to approximate location to city center when it can not match exact location.

Per documentation there is `fuzzyMatch(Boolean true:default)` option that can change this behavior.

Since I am using MapboxAPI directly through URL I tried following but all of them are returning same result set.

```
/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/[url_encoded_address_text].json?fuzzyMatch=true&access_token=pk.abc...
/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/[url_encoded_address_text].json?fuzzyMatch=false&access_token=pk.abc...
/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/[url_encoded_address_text].json?fuzzyMatch=1&access_token=pk.abc...
/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/[url_encoded_address_text].json?fuzzyMatch=0&access_token=pk.abc...
```

Looks like fuzzyMatch option does not do anything.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using it correctly with the true/false params ([docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/#forward-geocoding)):

```
/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/[url_encoded_address_text].json?fuzzyMatch=true&access_token=pk.abc...
/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/[url_encoded_address_text].json?fuzzyMatch=false&access_token=pk.abc...
```

Using the example from the docs, a query using `types=place` of `wahsington` and the `fuzzyMatch=true` param yields `"place_name": "Washington, District of Columbia, United States"` while using `fuzzyMatch=false` yields no results.

False - `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/wahsington.json?access_token=pk.abc...&fuzzyMatch=false&types=place`

True - `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/wahsington.json?access_token=pk.abc...&fuzzyMatch=true&types=place`